# Write down the time when app is closed or enters backgound

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

I want my app to record the time when it was closed by the user or it enters the background and be shown when it is opened next time. I have the following code, however it doesn't work.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
     _ = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "lastTime")
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        let terminateTime = NSDate()
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(terminateTime, forKey: "lastTime")
        defaults.synchronize()
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you are setting the value again when launching the app, instead of getting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a variable `lastTime`

  ```
  var lastTime : NSDate!
  ```
- In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` register a default value and read it:

  ```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let defaultValues = ["lastTime" : NSDate()]
    defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)

    lastTime = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("lastTime") as! NSDate
    return true
  }
  ```

  The default value is only considered on the first run.
- In `applicationWillResignActive:` save it:

  ```
  func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    let terminateTime = NSDate()
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(terminateTime, forKey: "lastTime")
  }
  ```

  `synchronize()` is not needed

Comment: Thanks vadian, works perfectly. I know where the problem is.